# Gnuplot: wrong numbers on scaled color bar

Tags: information-graphics, gnuplot

I used gnuplot to create a 3D surface from a data file "3D.txt" written in three columns x y z. I saw that the numbers on the color bar are ~40000 although the peak of my graph (z_max) is around 14 [see picture].

How can I solve this? I used simple code like:

```
gnuplot> set palette rgbformulae 22, 13, -31
gnuplot> splot "3D.txt"
```

[image]